# Linear Programming in Matlab help

Tags: linear-programming, matlab

I wrote the following code in Matlab in order to solve a problem:

% Problem design.

C = [6 ; 4 ; 7; 5];

A = [1 2 1 2 ; 6 5 3 2 ; 3 4 9 12];

B = [20 ; 100 ; 75 ];

% Our variables X are positive (thus lower bounded by zeros)

% but not upper bounded.

LB = zeros(size(C));

UB = inf(size(C));

% Solve using linprog. Use empty matrices for Aeq and beq because

% we do not have additional equality constraints.

[ X , val ] = linprog(C,A,B,[],[],LB,UB);

% Output results.

disp(X)

disp(val)

However, X becomes the LB vector and as such the solution is 0. This happens for whatever value i set the LB vector to be, the function seems to substitute X for the LB vector. Any help would be appreciated as i thought this code was fine.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to solve the problem

$$\min c^Tx $$

subject to

$$Ax \le b$$

$$x \ge l$$

where every entry of $A$ and $b$ and $c$ are nonnegative.

Hence the smaller each component of $x$ is, the more optimal is the solution.

Edit:

note that $\max c^Tx = - \min (-c)^Tx$

Comment: It is meant to be a maximisation problem, which is why the answers i am getting are confusing me.

Comment: let $C = -C$ then

Answer (score 0):

So the linear program function in matlab always finds the minimum of your objective function as seen [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/linprog.html).  Looks like you set up everything right to find the minimum optimal answer, but if you are trying to find the maximum, you need to multiply your objective function by a negative because:

$max$ $c^Tx = -min -c^Tx$